How to run high graphics demanding programs on dedicated gpu in laptop
My laptop specs is :
Amd Ryzen 5000 series
Nvidia Rtx 3050 Laptop gpu
16 Gb Ram
512 gb ssd
Asus Zenbook 14
The problem is that no matter what I do, in Nvidia control panel and add the programs in display graphics setting of win 11 and selecting performance mode the high graphics demanding applications still run on the integrated amd graphics. When I installed a fps counter to check on which gpu the applications are running, the applications were running on amd and not on rtx.
Also the rtx is not detecting in fps monitering app. :/
Please help me.
I have tried all the videos in YouTube. But still no fix.
I tried to change the global settings in nvidia control panel to high performance processor(rtx 3050).
And also add the program to display settings in win 11 and change it to high performance.
I was expecting to run high graphics demanding applications on the rtx and not on the integrated amd graphics but still no fix.
